# How can I create a web-based table of contents that links to specific places within a diverse collection of documents?

Tags: search, pdf, indexing, documents, tableofcontents

How can I create a web-based table of contents that links to specific places in a variety of document formats (unspecified: I assume Excel, PowerPoint, Word, and PDF)? Also, how could I search within the documents and create an index? Both the search results and the index should link to specific places within the documents.

My first thought was to convert all of the documents to PDF, [create destinations](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/9.0/Standard/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7ca7.w.html) within the PDFs, and [link to the destinations](http://www.planetpdf.com/enterprise/article.asp?ContentID=6426) from a web page. I'm definitely open to other ideas, though.

I'm pretty sure the documents will not be set up in a way that would be easy to automate adding bookmarks and links within PDFs; i.e., Word documents probably won't use heading styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PDF's, there's a question asked at almost exactly the same time as yours:

[PDF Open Parameters: comment=commentID doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343114/pdf-open-parameters-comment-commentid-doesnt-work/5345606#5345606)

He's got everything but the commentID working (page number, zoom setting, etc).  Dunno about the other formats.