# PDF Open Parameters: comment=commentID doesn't work

Tags: html, pdf, command-line, hyperlink, command-line-arguments

According to Adobe's Manual on [PDF Open Parameters](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf) PDF files can be opened with certain parameters from command line or from a link in HTML.
These **open Parameters** include `page=pagenum`, `zoom=scale`, `comment=commentID` and others (the first parameter should be preceded with a # and the next should be preceded with a &

The official [PDF Open Parameters](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf) from adobe gives this example:

`#page=1&comment=452fde0e-fd22-457c-84aa-2cf5bed5a349`

but the **comment** part doesn't work for me!

`page=pagenum` and `zoom=scale` work for me well. But `comment=commentID` **does not work**. I tried on Adobe reader 6.0.0 and Adobe Pro Extended 9.0.0: I can't get to the specified comment.

Also, I get the comment ID by exporting the comments in XFDF format and in the resulting file, there is a `name` attribute for every comment that I hope corresponds to the ID (well, the appearance looks like the example in the manual).

I thought maybe there is a setting that I should first enable (or maybe disable in adobe) or maybe I am getting the comment IDs wrong, or maybe something else?!

Any help would be extremely appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, you must include a `page=X` along with your `comment=foo`.  Your copied sample has it, but it's copied from the docs, not something you did yourself.

Are you missing a `page=` when setting `comment`?

---

BASTARDS!

From the last page of the manual you linked:

> URL Limitations
>   ●Only one digit following a decimal point is retained for float values.
>   ●Individual parameters, together with their values (separated by & or #), **can be no greater then 32 characters in length**.

Emphasis added.

The comment ID is a 16-byte value expressed as hex, with four hyphens thrown in to break up the monotony.  That's 36 characters right there... starting with "comment=" adds another 8 characters.  44 characters total.

According to that, a comment ID can NEVER WORK, **including the samples they show in their docs**.

Are you just trying it on the command line, or have you tried via a web browser too?  I wonder if that makes a difference.  If not, we're looking at a feature that CANNOT WORK.  EVER... and probably never has.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Yes, I did so too. `"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 6.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /A "#page=3&comment=a9178992-ccbf-4f15-a792-a01320b066c3=OpenActions" "d:\FDF\doc1.pdf"`. OR `"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 6.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /A "#page=3&zoom=1000&comment=a9178992-ccbf-4f15-a792-a01320b066c3=OpenActions" "d:\FDF\doc1.pdf"`, and other variations including omission of `=OpenActions`. It **always works, except `comment=<commentID>`**. I also tried to change the commentIDs by changin nametag in FDF files and re-importing them, but never works. Thank you very much for your support

Comment: Maybe I am getting the commentID wrong? I look at the XFDF file that I export from acrobat: `<text color="#00FF00" opacity="0.505005" creationdate="D:20110314092638+03'30'" flags="print,nozoom,norotate" date="D:20110314092641+03'30'" name="3c2b1bf6-7631-45ac-a3b4-45dc92bde066" icon="Circle" page="0" rect="109.167007,122.248001,129.167007,142.248001" rotation="90" subject="Sticky Note" title="Mostafa">` There is a **name** property that I think must be the commentID? Or maybe there is something in acrobat's options that I must check to allow navigating to a commentID?

Comment: Yes Mark. You are right....BASTARDS! : )) It took me 5 whole days to work around this problem....I believe you are right...the commentID can never be of enough size (I tried on FireFox 3.6 and IE 6, but in vein)...Guess I have to find another method :( **Thanks you very much Mark, for relieving me after almost a week of stress**

Comment: The PDFOpen parameters support named destinations, as well as zoom bounding boxes (limited to 32 characters total again).  The xfdf contains the comment's "rect".  Keep in mind that only the first digit after the decimal place is kept with floating point numbers.  Good hunting.

Comment: .....Oh! by the way, changing the commentID from the XFDF file to a small string and re-importing it to the PDF doesn't solve this problem and there was one person in a forum (unfortunately I can't find the link now) who claimed it worked for him-although there were others who on the same forum who had the same problem.